# Inserting hash symbol in an sms as text

Tags: c#, .net, hash, symbols

I faced a problem in asp dotnet when an functionality requires an sms text containing a hash symbol to be sent after execution and the problem is that the text after the hash symbol gets truncated when it is received in the mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the symbol.

For instance :

Don't use this ------------  Use this

```
     !              %21
     "              %22
     #              %23
```

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp